# Netwon's method going from $\Delta w$ to iteration?

Tags: self-learning, nonlinear-optimization

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~wilambm/pap/2011/K10149_C012.pdf) to learn about Levenberg-Maquardt and I'm going through Newton's method. I understand most of the math in that document but I can't see how the jump from 12.14 to 12.15 happens.

Here's my understanding: We have $-\textbf{g} = \textbf{H}\Delta \textbf{w}$. We got this based on the fact that at the minima, $\textbf{g}$ would be zero. Since we plugged this into the equation 12.9, we should get a value of $\Delta \textbf{w}$ that directly takes us to the minima. Why do we need to iterate multiple times?

Is there some implicit assumption that requires the iteration?

(I couldn't find a self-study tag on this forum - is it called something else here?)

Comment: In each step you are minimizing a quadratic approximation of the objective… But anyway, this is the wrong site for this question.

Comment: Where should i move it to?

Comment: Try at math.stackexchange or scicomp.stackexchange but also include the background and the step you don't understand in you question.

Comment: Can a mod please move this?

Comment: Since the question needs to be edited to stay open on, e.g., SciComp.SE (for example, you should put the equations into the post) and you need to register there anyway to be able to vote on and accept answers, it's probably easier to write a new question and delete this one. (But as Dirk pointed out, $\Delta w$ gets you directly to the minimizer of the quadratic model, which is *not* the minimizer of the original nonquadratic problem. But it should be closer to it, hence the need for iteration.)